# react-native: how to modify the format in which data is stored in AsyncStorage?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

`AsyncStorage` is storing data in `{"chosenDate":"2018-12-10","text":"llibl"}` format. 
But I want it to store it in `{'2012-05-22': [{text: 'item 1 - any js object'}]` or `'2012-05-25': [{text: 'item 3 - any js object'},{text: 'any js object'}]` format

**OR**

Is it possible to change the stored format when I use `componetDidMount()` to `getState()` ?

**Below is the code for my component:**

So, I have a form with TextInput and DatePicker and a button and on click of the button, the form entries are stored using `AsyncStorage`.

```
class Reminder extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let formatDate = new Date();
        this.state = {
            chosenDate: formatDate.toISOString().split('T')[0],
            text: '',
        };

        this.handleChangeInput = this.handleChangeInput.bind(this);
        this.saveData = this.saveData.bind(this);
    }

    handleChangeInput = (input) =>  {
        this.setState({text:input});
    }

    //save the input
    saveData() {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(this.state));
    }
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <View>
                <Form style={styles.formContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.formView}>

                            < TextInput
                            placeholder = "Set your reminder"
                            onChangeText={this.handleChangeInput}
                            value={this.state.text}
                            />

                        <DatePicker
                            defaultDate={new Date()}
                            minimumDate={new Date(2018, 1, 1)}
                            maximumDate={new Date(2019, 12, 31)}
                            locale={"en"}
                            timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={undefined}
                            modalTransparent={false}
                            animationType={"fade"}
                            androidMode={"default"}
                            placeHolderText="Select date"
                            textStyle={{ color: "green" }}
                            placeHolderTextStyle={{ color: "#d3d3d3" }}

                        />
                        <Text style={styles.datePicker}>
                            {this.state.chosenDate}
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.footer}>
                        <Button block success style={styles.saveBtn} 
                        onPress={ () => 
                            {
                              this.saveData()
                              console.log('save data',this.state);
                              Alert.alert('Yay!!', 'Succefully saved.')
                            }
                        } 
                           >
                            <Icon type='MaterialIcons' name='done' />                        
                        </Button>
                    </View>
                </Form>
            </View> 
        );
    }
}

export default Reminder;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// you can achieve this by formatting the state before you store to asyncStorage.

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    chosenDate: "2018-12-10",
    text: "library1",
    text1: "library2"
  };
}


async saveData() {
  let { chosenDate, ...restOfState } = this.state;
  let textArray = Object.entries(restOfState).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));
  let formattedState = { [chosenDate]: textArray };
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(formattedState));
}

async getData() {
  let storedData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("key");
  return storedData ? JSON.parse(storedData) : {};
}


 render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title="SaveData"
        onPress={() => {
          this.saveData().then(resp => {console.log("data saved")});
        }}
      />
      <Button
        style={{ margin: 20, padding: 20 }}
        title="getData"
        onPress={() => {
          this.getData().then(resp => {
            console.log("Stored Data", resp);
          });
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

```js
// Sample Code

let state = {"chosenDate":"2018-12-10","text":"llibl", text1:"llib2"};
let {chosenDate, ...restOfState} =  state;
console.log(`chosenDate: ${chosenDate}, restOfState: ${restOfState}`);


let textArray = Object.entries(restOfState).map(([key, value])=> ({[key]: value}))

let foramttedState = {[chosenDate]:textArray};

console.log('foramttedState :',foramttedState);
```

Comment: it works. but I am unable to insert more than one text values... unlike your example has `text` and `text1` corresponding to same `chosenDate`

Comment: Did you have defined the text1 as a state variable.

Comment: yes, I have. If you look at my state variables, you can I have two state variables `chosenDate` and `text`

Comment: apologies for a late reply. I was not well.